# A new row is not added to the table after calling the function via Npgsql in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am developing a program that interacts with tables from the database. I want to add some data to the table by calling a function inside the button click event handler.
The problem is that after clicking on the button, nothing is added to the table, but if I call the function like this

```
SELECT * FROM insertestimate(170711, 'uagay'::text, 'test'::text, 5, date '2020-11-23');
```

through the terminal, everything works fine.

```
public void insertEstimate(parametres param)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    NpgsqlParameter par = new NpgsqlParameter(":date", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date);
    par.Value = dateTime;
    sql = "SELECT * FROM insertEstimate (:ID, :subjectName, :teacherName, :estimate, :date)";
    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", param.gradeBookNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("subjectName", param.subjectName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("teacherName", param.teacherName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("estimate", param.estimation);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(par);
}
```

**function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insertestimate(
    _id integer,
    _subjectname text,
    _teachername text,
    _estimate integer,
    _dateofestimate date)
RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO studentsGrade (id, subjectname, teachername, grade, dateoftheestimate) 
    VALUES (_ID, _subjectName, _teacherName, _estimate, _dateOfEstimate);
END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Looks like you are creating the command in C# but not executing it.

Comment: Not familiar with `npgsql`, but I going to guess that you have done a `COMMIT` on the transaction.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh yes, is it. Thanks!